# ROS2 cam2image non default video device

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

how can I switch the video device when I start up cam2image with ROS2? I hope to find something like

> ros2 run image_tools cam2image video0:=video2

Best wishes

Sebastian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338896/ros2-cam2image-non-default-video-device/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2019-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe you can (from [here](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/e1453fc25f0af51abe5aa6d75f5601f4ab69395c/image_tools/src/cam2image.cpp#L91-L93)):

> ```
> if (!burger_mode_) {
> ```

```
  // Initialize OpenCV video capture stream.
  // Always open device 0.
  cap.open(0);
  ..
}
```

The help output also doesn't seem to give the impression this is possible:

> ```
> Usage:
> ```

```
 -h: This message.
 -r: Reliability QoS setting:
    0 - best effort
    1 - reliable (default)
 -d: Depth of the queue: only honored if used together with 'keep last'. 10 (default)
 -f: Publish frequency in Hz. 30 (default)
 -k: History QoS setting:
    0 - only store up to N samples, configurable via the queue depth (default)
    1 - keep all the samples
 -s: Camera stream:
    0 - Do not show the camera stream
    1 - Show the camera stream
 -x WIDTH and -y HEIGHT. Resolution.
    Please type v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
    to obtain a list of valid values.
 -b: produce images of burgers rather than connecting to a camera
 -t TOPIC: use topic TOPIC instead of the default
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2019-12-01**:
Hi gvdhoorn,

Based on the code, you seem to be right. Is there a good reason to connect this statically to video0? Or are other packages avilable with a more flexible interface?

Best wishes!

Sebastian

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-01**:\

> Is there a good reason to connect this statically to video0?

This package is a demo package, it was never designed to be a generic replacement for something like `usb_cam` (the ROS 1 pkg).

> Or are other packages avilable with a more flexible interface?

No, I don't. I'm sorry.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-12-02**:
Contributing a patch to add a new command line argument to pass the device name should be pretty straight forward.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-03**:
That would indeed not be too difficult and would make a great addition.

@Poseidonius: please consider contributing that change. It would appear it would help you and it would help future users as well.